# When should one use h:link instead of h:commandLink?

Tags: jsf-2

If I have a JSF page that I want to link to where I don't need to communicate anything to that page and don't need to perform any validation on the page I'm linking from, should I always use an h:link?

Do I lose anything by not using a h:commandLink (with immediate="true" or execute="@this")?

Is there any difference between h:link and h:commandLink in this scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `h:link` will fire a full GET request. Only JSF lifecycle phases 1 (restore view) and 6 (render response) will be invoked. No conversion, no validation, no action.

Thus `immediate="true"` and `execute="@this"` won't work (they are not available for `h:link` at all).

Use `h:link` for pure page to page navigation and `h:commandLink` (which fires a POST request) if input data needs to be processed on the server.

*Addendum:*

As per BalusC's comment lifecycle phases 2 to 5 are not skipped for a GET request if the target page contains `f:viewParam`s.

Comment: In the original question, the references to immediate and execute in  were for commandLink, not h:link

Comment: The first paragraph is not entirely correct. The other phases will be invoked when the target page has `<f:viewParam>`s.